# Date pattern comparison and matching

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm looking for a smart way to compare a date pattern with another date pattern and of course especially with a specific date. The date pattern I have to use has in its compact form four members.

```
first octet year
   0 .. 254 = 1900 .. 2154
        255 = any year
second octet month
   1 ..  12 = January .. December
         13 = odd months
         14 = even months
        255 = any month
third octet day of month
   1 ..  31 = day of month
         32 = last day of month
         33 = odd days of month
         34 = even days of month
        255 = any day of month
fourth octet day of week
   1 ..   7 = Monday .. Sunday
        255 = any day of week
```

Since the date pattern could be stored in an 32-bit integer, I thought about using bitmasks or somthing else to compare. The code example shows the inchoate class which I currently plan to use. But without "smartness". For every useful hint I would be grateful!

```cpp
#include <time.h>

class DatePattern
{
private:
   int year;
   int month;
   int dayOfMonth;
   int dayOfWeek;

public:
   DatePattern(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int dayOfWeek)
   {
      // validate year
      if (year < 1900 || year > 2154)
      {
         year = 255;
      }
      this->year = year;

      // validate month
      if (month < 1 || month > 14)
      {
         month = 255;
      }
      this->month = month;

      // validate day of month
      if (dayOfMonth < 1 || dayOfMonth > 34)
      {
         dayOfMonth = 255;
      }
      this->dayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;

      // validate day of week
      if (dayOfWeek < 1 || dayOfWeek > 7)
      {
         dayOfWeek = 255;
      }
      this->dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
   }

   bool Match(struct tm * timeinfo)
   {
      // validate time pointer
      if (timeinfo == NULL)
      {
         time_t rawtime;
         time(&rawtime);
         timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
      }

      // check year
      if (year != 255 && timeinfo->tm_year != year)
      {
         return false;
      }

      // check month
      int currentMonth = timeinfo->tm_mon + 1;
      bool oddMonth = (currentMonth % 2 ? true : false);
      if (month != 255 && (month == 13 && !oddMonth) && (month == 14 && oddMonth) && month != currentMonth)
      {
         return false;
      }

      // check day of month
      bool oddDay = (timeinfo->tm_mday % 2 ? true : false);
      if (dayOfMonth != 255 && (dayOfMonth == 33 && !oddDay) && (dayOfMonth == 34 && oddDay) && dayOfMonth != timeinfo->tm_mday)
      {
         return false;
      }

      // check day of week
      int currentDayOfWeek = (timeinfo->tm_wday == 0 ? 7 : timeinfo->tm_wday);
      if (dayOfWeek != 255 && dayOfWeek != currentDayOfWeek)
      {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

   long Compact()
   {
      return (((year - 1900) << 24) | (month << 16) | (dayOfMonth << 8) | (dayOfWeek));
   }

   int Year()
   {
      return year;
   }

   int Month()
   {
      return month;
   }

   int DayOfMonth()
   {
      return dayOfMonth;
   }

   int DayOfWeek()
   {
      return dayOfWeek;
   }
};

int main ()
{
   DatePattern pattern(-1, 6, -1, 2); // every Tuesday in June
   bool result = pattern.Match(NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

So my question is: Does anybody know a better way to compare a date with a date pattern? Are there already libraries or known implementations which working with date pattern in a similar way?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Spook I have concretized the question.

Comment: It depends very much on what kind of comparison you need. From how your pattern is defined I take it you regard two dates as more similar when they are both in even (or both in odd) months. That's a very special notion of date similarity. I'd start by listing up all the criteria for similarity you are interested in, and then look for a library (they may not be any, though).

Comment: Also, be careful not to turn this into a "are there any libraries for X" type of question. Those tend to get closed as not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

This is how would I do it:

- Create class Day, which accepts a value 1..31, 32, 33, 34, 255 and stores information about its nature (actual day or rule);
- Overload == operator on class Day, such that it can be compared with another Day using your rules;
- Implement DayOfWeek, Month, Year classes in the similar manner;
- Implement class Date, which aggregates DayOfWeek, Day, Month, Year and can be constructed either with specific date (d/m/y) or with your "encoded" date;
- Overload == operator on class Date, such that one Date can be compared with another by comparing their Day, DayOfWeek, Month and Year parts.